# Controller not getting called though AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jsp page with 2 dropdown. the second dropdown should populate based on  the value selected from first dropdown I am using AJAX for this to call a controller method on selecting the first dropdown to return the values for the second dropdown as json. On clicking submit entire form will be submitted to controller method. But on selecting the first dropdown, I am not getting any request on the controller method.

Jsp file

```js
alert("Ok");
("#selectCategory").onChange(function() {
  var categoryId = $(this).val();
  alert(categoryId);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/categories/" + categoryId,
    success: function(data) {
      var slctSubcat = $('#selectSubcat'),
        option = "";
      slctSubcat.empty();

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        option = option + "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" +
          data[i].subcateogory_name + "</option>";
      }
      slctSubcat.append(option);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("error");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<form action="/show" method="post" modelAttribute="model">
  <select class="form-control" id="selectCategory" name="sel">
    <option value="Alto">Alto</option>
    <option value="Esteem">Esteem</option>
  </select> <br>
  <select class="form-control" id="selectSubcat">
    <option value="-1" label="-Select-" />
  </select>
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Controller method

```
@GetMapping("/categories/{categoryId}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> get(@PathVariable("categoryId") String categoryId)
    {
    System.out.println("inside controller get  "+categoryId);
        ArrayList<String> l= new ArrayList<String>();
        if(categoryId.equals("Alto"))
        {
            l.add("Alto Model 1");
            l.add("Alto Model 2");
            return l;
        }
        else if(categoryId.equals("Esteem"))
        {
            l.add("Esteem Model 1");
            l.add("Esteem Model 2");
            return l;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I make a separate rest call to that controller method , I am getting the response as json  *[
    "Esteem Model 1",
    "Esteem Model 2"
]*, but through ajax, the request is not going.I am new to Ajax. Can someone please correct me if the below ajax code is wrong ?

Comment: Are you getting alert(categoryId) this alert value?

Comment: `("#selectCategory")` typo in the question?  Missing `$` -> `$("#selectCategory")` - as above, are you getting that first alert?

Comment: Check the network tab of the browser - is it attempting to send *any* request anywhere?  That will also tell you what it's sending to compare with your manual send.

Comment: No ,I am not getting alert alert(categoryId)  . I am only getting  alert("Ok").Also in  the browser console , I am getting  error -  login:16 **Uncaught TypeError: "#selectCategory".onChange is not a function**

Comment: @freedomn-m , If i add  **$ -> $("#selectCategory")** , I am getting error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**  in browser console.

Comment: My bad - thought this was tagged [jquery] but you're not using jquery at all (`$ is not defined`) - wait... so how do you expect `$.ajax` to work when you do get that far if you're not using jquery?  Are you just missing the jquery include?

Comment: *"I am getting..."* - please include *all* relevant information, especially error messages in the question in the first instance.

Comment: "*I am not getting any request on the controller*" - because your js code isn't getting anywhere near that

Comment: @freedomn-m, Yes I had missed the jquery include .I am new to jquery and Ajax.After including and jquery and doing few changes, its working fine now.I am getting the request on the controller after selecting the first dropdown and my second dropdown is getting populated with tha values sent from the controller.Thanks for the help.